# capture card for thunderbolt 3.0

Tags: mac, video-capture

I'm a youtube gamer and I'm interested in making the transition from pc to mac. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with macs and any challenges their usb thunderbolts will pose. I want to get the 2017 macbook pro. It has four thunderbolt 3.0 ports. Will normal video capture cards like the eglato hd60 be able to connect to the thunderbolt port fine? My concern is that I also want to have an external hard drive connected as well due to the limited amount of space on the macbook. I edit and post ps4/xbox one gaming videos.

Comment: Yes. You will need a USB-C to USB 3 adapter, but the HD60 is compatible with Macs. Edit: this assumes the HD60 USB device, NOT the HD60 Pro PCIe card

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt is a much better connection than USB 3 for these purposes.  Thunderbolt, when fully implemented, is actually able to function as an external 4x PCI-E connector in addition to a bunch of other things.  You can use a cheap adapter that will allow a USB 3.1 connection (which is backward compatible to previous USB standards) or you can buy a new device that is Thunderbolt 3 compatible and will be able to make use of the added bandwidth that Thunderbolt 3 supports.